# Proper format for PDO and MySQL IN/NOT IN queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For reasons that should be obvious, this is murder to search for...

How do I do this in PDO:

```
SELECT thing FROM things WHERE thing_uid IN ( ... )
```

My particular use case is a string built by exploding an array taken from a form with several dozen checkboxes. In standard MySQL this is very easy...

```
$thingString = implode("', '", $thingArray);
$q = "SELECT thing FROM things WHERE thing_uid IN ('$thingString')";
```

but I want that to benefit from PDO's anti-injection protection... bound params and all that. So how can I do it?

Comment: @Kris The question says nothing about binding the table name. It's about having a variable number of placeholders in `IN()` queries.

Comment: kris you have no idea what I'm talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an array of as many `?` as you have values, and throw that into the query.

```
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($thingArray), '?');
$sql = "SELECT thing FROM things WHERE thing_uid IN (" . implode(',', $placeholders) . ")";
```

Comment: Could also just use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Comment: so I prepare that with the placeholder **?** equal in number to my params and then `$stmt->execute($thingArray);` and I'm good to go, correct? (can't test at the moment, so I'm asking)