# Trouble with select query using implode variable in php?

Tags: php

I dont know whether it's a duplicate one or not?

Here is what i'm trying:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('db.php');
     $valid_data=$_POST['data'];
     if(isset($_POST['data']))
    {
     $list = isset($_SESSION['strtpnt1']) ? $_SESSION['strtpnt1'] : array();
     $_SESSION['strtpnt1'][] =$valid_data;
     $a=implode(',',$_SESSION['strtpnt1']);
    }
  ?>
```

when i use print_r for $_SESSION['strtpnt1'] i could see like this:

```
     array (size=5)
     0 => string 'trivandrum' (length=10)
     1 => string 'kochi' (length=5)
     2 => string 'nagercoil' (length=9)
     3 => string 'thrissur' (length=8)
```

I found nothing wrong with that

when i echoed the imploded variable i find the value like this:

```
      trivandrum,kochi,nagercoil,thrissur
```

When i tested the imploded data in wampserver phpmyadmin's sql like this i could get an error message:

```
  select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN(trivandrum,kochi,nagercoil,thrissur)
```

the error message is:

```
        Unknown column 'trivandrum' in 'where clause'
```

But the query works when string value is passed ie 'trivandrum','kochi' etc.

i dont know what is wrong with my query ...here is the query part

```
  $sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN('".$a."')";
```

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: you mean PDO ...I dont know mch about that ...

Comment: i have same problem before, pass in values from variable, prepared statements solve my problem

Comment: k  hw to do that ...i hve no idea in it...do i completely want to change my mysql queries...Any other suggestions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you can try this but prepared statement is best for it. You can use PDO or MYSQLi . it doesn't work for you because NOT IN needs the list to individually be quoted and separated by commas.

```
  $a=$_SESSION['strtpnt1'];
  $new_a= "'" . implode("','", $a) . "'";
  $sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where 
 start NOT IN($new_a)";
```

Similar Ideas
:[Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

[Proper format for PDO and MySQL IN/NOT IN queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062576/proper-format-for-pdo-and-mysql-in-not-in-queries)

Comment: can i ask u a question?

Comment: Glad it works for you. Best of luck.yes bro you can ask question? That's why we are in SO

Comment: If i wish to use PDO ,do i wanna change it in all my pages...sorry to ask u like this...I'm a beginner ?

Comment: I think you should read it first http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: k fine i get it now...u r an amaizing guide...i thank u once again for getting u in time...

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your parameter `$a` value, all values inside `IN()` should be quoted and separated by commas.

Change your code like following:

```
$a=implode("','",$_SESSION['strtpnt1']); // ',' => "','"

$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN('".$a."');";// no change

// NOW the SQL query will became:  select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN('trivandrum','kochi','nagercoil','thrissur');
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN('".$a."')";

will querying like this :

$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN('trivandrum,kochi,nagercoil,thrissur')";

which will treat as a whole string

you have to do in passing variable
$a=implode("','",$_SESSION['strtpnt1']);